# ImportError: No module named pydoop.hdfs in Oozie python workflow

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I wrote a python script which copies local files to HDFS.

Upgraded python version 2.6 to 2.7 in all nodes of cluster. Installed pydoop-1.0 version and using CDH 5.4

If I run the py script in command line it is working perfectly. This same script is throwing below error when I run in oozie.

Error:

```
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs
ImportError: No module named pydoop.hdfs
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class 
[org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
```

Oozie workflow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app name="FileLogPy" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
<start to="FileLog"/>
<action name="FileLog">
<shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
       <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
       <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
       <prepare>
             <delete path='${outputHadoopDirectory}'/>
       </prepare>
       <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
           </property>
       </configuration>
      <exec>python</exec>
      <argument>FileLog.py</argument>
      <argument>${inputDir}</argument>
     <argument>${outputHadoopDirectory}</argument>
     <argument>${kpi}</argument>
     <argument>${sourceName}</argument>
      <argument>${wf:id()}</argument>
      <file>${LogScriptPath}#FileLog.py</file>
      <capture-output/>
  </shell>
  <ok to="end"/>
  <error to="kill"/>    
</action>

<kill name="kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Added hashbang to the script. So that it will not check for python 2.6 version.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs
```

Need Help !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be because of the lack of pydoop library in all the nodes. If you run the script locally, the python script is getting triggered in the same machine. In that machine you have pydoop library. But if you run this script through oozie, this script can execute in any of the nodes in the cluster. So install all the required python packages in all the nodes (nodemanager nodes) in the hadoop cluster.

Comment: I have installed pydoop in all the nodes in cluster. Tested this script in all nodes individually. Worked fine. But in oozie i'm still getting this error.